# KeyLogger in MacOS

Tags: macos, c++11, keyevent, macos-carbon, keylogger

I am trying to create keylogger for MacOS.
In order to record key events I am using this:

```
CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(
    kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, kCGEventTapOptionDefault, eventMask, CGEventCallback, nullptr);
```

In CGEventCallback I had planned to keep member variable increasing number of keystrokes. But I cant have that callback as method class. Right now it is free function
Could someone tell me how to modify code to have CGEventCallback as method class? If it not possible what are my alternatives

Thanks and regards

Comment: You can call a method from the callback function. Use `refcon` (the last parameter of `CGEventTapCreate`) to pass the data you need.

Comment: What do you mean by data? parameters of the callback ?

Comment: Which data do you need to call the method?

Comment: I finally solved it adding static method